# A more advanced example of Google Analytics EasyTracker library (on Android)

Tags: android, google-analytics

In an example provided by Google ([http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src/tracking/mobile/android/EasyTracker)), it doesn't show how to customize page tracking. For example, where in the code should I call something like:

```
Tracker.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).trackPageView("/MyActivity/"+myVariable);
```

Does anyone has experience on using this library? I also couldn't find its documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is to make sure your activities inherit from `TrackedActivity`, and they will be automatically tracked (considering you also enabled `ga_auto_activity_tracking`).

If you want to get the tracker object—to record events, for instance—just call `EasyTracker.getTracker()`.

**Edit**: After a small discussion in the comments with Georgy Gobozov, I should add that you should not use EasyTracker before your `onStart()` method, where you call `super.onStart()`. It's on TrackedActivity's `onStart()` method that it calls `trackActivityStart()`, [which starts a new session](http://code.google.com/p/analytics-api-samples/source/browse/trunk/src/tracking/mobile/android/EasyTracker/Library/src/com/google/android/apps/analytics/easytracking/EasyTracker.java#251).

Comment: Hey, I am trying to call EasyTracker.getTracker().trackPageView("/HomeScreen"); but I am getting NullPointer, can't understand why.

Comment: Make sure that you're inheriting from TrackedActivity and that you're calling super.onCreate() on your onCreate() method.

Comment: Thanks for reply, problem was that I have tried to call EasyTracker in onCreate method, in onStart and other places everything works fine

Comment: Oh, yes, my bad. EasyTracker reads your properties on the onStart() method, so you can't use it on the onCreate() method of your first activity. It would be wise to avoid using EasyTracker on all onCreate() methods.

Comment: @goncalossilva  TrackedActivity is not necessary if you are using EasyTracker.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow Google's instructions on setting up screen tracking: [Screen Tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/screens)

Basically, you can specify your app's screens (activities) that you want to be automatically tracked in your **analytics.xml** file.

Answer (score 0):

you would place that in the part of your code that corresponds to what you would call a page view or event in your app.

For instance, if you wanna track how many people look at a help menu, place it in the code that is invoked whenever the help menu button is pushed, or in the code that displays the help menu (and have the myVariable variable be something like "help menu").